# ionic/angular ng-click calls function not with the correct argument

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with ionic/angular on android. There are two buttons in a form:

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-content>
    <form>
      <div class="list">
        ...
        <label class="item">
          <button ng-click="prefsSave(true)" class="button button-block button-positive">Save & Check</button>
          <button ng-click="prefsSave(false)" class="button button-block button-positive">Save</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

The function to be called on click is defined in the controller:

```
$scope.prefsSave = function(check) {
  ...
}
```

The function is called always with ''true'' regardless of which button was pressed. What is wrong?

Comment: The above works for me, passing true/false correctly. Could you provide more code about the controller?

Comment: You can leave more code control? What you wear now works for me.

Comment: I've added all of the surrounding HTML tags, to reproduce the problem. See also my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the problem was caused by the HTML *label* tag. If I'm using *span* instead *label* it works correctly. I do not say,that I understand, but it works. So the final HTML:

```
<ion-modal-view>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form>
      <div class="list">
        ...
        <span class="item">
          <button ng-click="prefsSave(true)" class="button button-block button-positive">Save & Check</button>
          <button ng-click="prefsSave(false)" class="button button-block button-positive">Save</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```